# Slim down bloated javascript - multi-step transitions

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

This is my first question, and a long one.
Please bear with me.

I'm trying to create an animated multi-step form with progress indicator, using css translateX and javascript.
The form has 5 steps.

Html looks as follows.

First, the progress indicator.

```
<div class="progressbar>
<div class="progress" id="progress01">A</div>
<div class="progress" id="progress02">B</div>
<div class="progress" id="progress03">C</div>
<div class="progress" id="progress04">D</div>
<div class="progress" id="progress05">D</div>
</div>
```

Then, the actual steps of the form.
Each step has 'next' and 'previous' buttons.

```
<div id="container">
<div class="step" id="step01">TEXT
<span id="knopR12" class="knopR">next</span> 
</div>
<div class="step" id="step02">TEXT
<span id="knopL21" class="knopL">previous</span>
<span id="knopR23" class="knopR">next</span>
</div>
<div class="step" id="step03">TEXT
<span id="knopL32" class="knopL">previous</span>
<span id="knopR34" class="knopR">next</span>
</div>
<div class="step" id="step04">TEXT
<span id="knopL43" class="knopL">previous</span>
<span id="knopR45" class="knopR">next</span>
</div>
<div class="step" id="step05">TEXT
<span id="knopL54" class="knopL">previous</span>
</div>
</div>
```

In css, I gave the container a width, max-width, position, and overflow: hidden:

```
#container {position: relative; width: 96%, max-width: 1000px; 
overflow: hidden; margin: 0 auto;}
```

I positioned the steps out of the container, and out of sight:

```
.step {position: absolute; width: 100%; top: 0; left: -105%;}
```

I assigned all steps a transition:

```
.step {-webkit-transition: transform 1.4s cubic-bezier(0.50, 0, 0.40, 1);
-moz-transition: transform 1.4s cubic-bezier(0.50, 0, 0.40, 1);
-o-transition: transform 1.4s cubic-bezier(0.50, 0, 0.40, 1);
-ms-transition: transform 1.4s cubic-bezier(0.50, 0, 0.40, 1);
transition: transform 1.4s cubic-bezier(0.50, 0, 0.40, 1);
```

I brought the first step in view:

```
#step01 {position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;}
```

In js, I wrote a function to translate step1 from 0 to +150 (out of sight), and step2 from -105 to 0 (in view). This creates a sliding effect. Step1 slides out of view, step2 slides into view.

Like this:

```
function goTo12(){
var step01=document.getElementById('step01');   
var step02=document.getElementById('step02');   
var step03=document.getElementById('step03');   
var step04=document.getElementById('step04');   
var step05=document.getElementById('step05');   
step01.style.webkitTransform = "translateX(150%)"; 
step01.style.mozTransform = "translateX(150%)"; 
step01.style.msTransform = "translateX(150%)"; 
step01.style.Transform = "translateX(150%)";    
step02.style.webkitTransform = "translateX(105%)"; 
step02.style.mozTransform = "translateX(105%)"; 
step02.style.msTransform = "translateX(105%)"; 
step02.style.Transform = "translateX(105%)";
}
```

I wrote such functions for each and every translation: step1 to step2, step2 to step1, step2 to step3, step3 to step2, and so forth.

I then added event-listeners, and assigned the specific functions to the suitable buttons.

As for the buttons, I started by hiding all buttons, except for the first one, which is responsible for moving from step1 to step2:

```
.knopR {display: none;}
.knopL {display: none;}
#knopR12 {display: inline-block;}
```

I then went on to show and hide all buttons as needed, on an individual basis. Like this:

```
function goTo12(){ var step01=document.getElementById('step01');     
var step02=document.getElementById('step02');    
var step03=document.getElementById('step03');    
var step04=document.getElementById('step04');    
var step05=document.getElementById('step05');    
step01.style.webkitTransform = "translateX(150%)";  
step01.style.mozTransform = "translateX(150%)";  
step01.style.msTransform = "translateX(150%)";  
step01.style.Transform = "translateX(150%)";     
step02.style.webkitTransform = "translateX(105%)";  
step02.style.mozTransform = "translateX(105%)";  
step02.style.msTransform = "translateX(105%)";  
step02.style.Transform = "translateX(105%)";
document.getElementById('knopL21').style.display = "inline-block";  
document.getElementById('knopR12').style.display = "none"; 
document.getElementById('knopR23').style.display = "inline-block"; }
```

Finally, I had to deal with the progressbar.
In css, I started out by giving all progress items a light background-color, except for the first one, which got a darker background-color. The darker color marks the 'active' step:

```
.progress {display: inline-block; background-color: #DCDCDC; color: white;}
#progress01 {background-color: #708090;}
```

Then, for all items .progress, I created a transition from #DCDCDC to #708090:

```
.progress {-webkit-transition: background-color 1.4s ease-in-out; 
-moz-transition: background-color 1.4s ease-in-out; 
-o-transition: background-color 1.4s ease-in-out; 
-ms-transition: background-color 1.4s ease-in-out; 
transition: background-color 1.4s ease-in-out;}
```

Finally, in js, for all separate items .progress, I wrote a function which moves all steps to their appropriate places, which shows/hides all appropriate buttons, and which applies appropriate (active vs non-active) colors. This one such a function (out of 5):

```
function moveNow02() {
step01.style.webkitTransform = "translateX(150%)"; 
step01.style.mozTransform = "translateX(150%)"; 
step01.style.msTransform = "translateX(150%)"; 
step01.style.Transform = "translateX(150%)"; 
step02.style.webkitTransform = "translateX(105%)"; 
step02.style.mozTransform = "translateX(105)"; 
step02.style.msTransform = "translateX(105%)"; 
step02.style.Transform = "translateX(105%)";
step03.style.webkitTransform = "translateX(-105%)"; 
step03.style.mozTransform = "translateX(-105)"; 
step03.style.msTransform = "translateX(-105%)"; 
step03.style.Transform = "translateX(-105%)";
step04.style.webkitTransform = "translateX(-105%)"; 
step04.style.mozTransform = "translateX(-105)"; 
step04.style.msTransform = "translateX(-105%)"; 
step04.style.Transform = "translateX(-105%)";
step05.style.webkitTransform = "translateX(-105%)"; 
step05.style.mozTransform = "translateX(-105)"; 
step05.style.msTransform = "translateX(-105%)"; 
step05.style.Transform = "translateX(-105%)";
document.getElementById('knopR12').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('knopR23').style.display = "inline-block";
document.getElementById('knopR34').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('knopR45').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('knopRbestellen').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('knopL21').style.display = "inline-block";
document.getElementById('knopL32').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('knopL43').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('knopL54').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('progress05').style.backgroundColor = "#DCDCDC";
document.getElementById('progress04').style.backgroundColor = "#DCDCDC";
document.getElementById('progress03').style.backgroundColor = "#DCDCDC";
document.getElementById('progress02').style.backgroundColor = "#708090";
}
```

Now, all of this 'works'.
Steps slide in and out, background-color of the progressbar changes as expected, and the appropriate buttons are present.
However, I do understand that it must be possible to do this with far less code, especially on the javascript end. 
That's where I need help.

Comment: In current form your question sits at the limit of being off-topic, because improving code that works is not part of SO's allowed topics, so your question might be better suited on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Besides, it's highly unlikely that an answer to your question will ever help anyone other than yourself, which strips most of the incentive for anyone considering answering it. However, if you provide a ***runnable*** [mcve] (use `<>` button to add a runnable snippet), I'm willing to have a look and suggest optimizations.

Comment: I'm sorry. My knowledge of css and js is rudimentary at best. I can't put my question any better than this, unless I produce even more code, which doesn't seem advisable. Truth is, I'd like to learn how to use less code, and maybe get better results. But indeed, it 'works'.

Comment: You might feel more comfortable using a dedicated snippet service, like jsfiddle or similar. All you need is to place the markup, the js and the CSS in the correct panels and also add any external resources in correct order. Even though I might be able to recreate it from what you posted here, I'm not going to spend time on it, I believe you're the one who should create it. Note jsfiddle provides support for SCSS. And I believe codepen has support for less. Not sure, though.

Comment: I'll look into JSFiddle tomorrow. I'm not asking you to solve my problems. Some pointers however about eg how to tackle the js side might set me on my way.

Comment: Probably the biggest problem your code has is it's not [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). Whenever you find yourself writing the same thing more than once, you're probably better off putting it in a function and calling that function instead. If it has slight differences, just define them as parameters and pass them on.

Comment: Here's my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/RobOnceMore/2Lk1bsm5/.

Comment: It's very far from how it should be. It will take me some time and I'm not going to do it this evening, but I'll write an answer and give an example on how it should be done and which are the advantages of doing it properly.